# Is it possible to call a function as a parameter of another function in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

Is it possible to call a function as a parameter of another function in `Swift`??

I am making a sound effects app in `Swift` which uses different effects like `AVAudioUnitReverb()` and `AVAudioUnitDistortion()` etc. I wanted to create a single function and just be able to call which effects I wanted to do.

Comment: You can pass a function as a parameter of a function. You can either pass the function directly or by its name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in Swift functions are ***first-class types***, you can pass it as an argument to another function.

Example:

```
func testA() {
    print("Test A")
}

func testB(function: () -> Void) {
    function()
}

testB(testA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in functions as parameter my typing the parameter with the same signature.

As sunshine's example just deals with Void parameters and return types, I want to add another example

```
func plus(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}

func minus(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int {
    return x - y
}

func performOperation (x:Int, _ y:Int, op:(x:Int,y: Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return op(x: x, y: y)
}

let resultplus = performOperation(1, 2, op: plus) // -> 3
let resultminus = performOperation(1, 2, op: minus) // -> -1
```

<sub>**note**: Of course you should consider dynamic typed parameters. For simplicity here just Ints</sub>

this is called *Higher Order Functions* and in many languages this is the way of doing it. But often you don't won't to explicitly create functionss for it. Here Closures are a perfect tool:

The function `performOperation` stays untouched, but the operations are implemented differently:

```
let plus = { (x:Int, y:Int) -> Int in
    return x + y
}

let minus = { (x:Int, y:Int) -> Int in
    return x - y
}

let resultplus = performOperation(1, 2, op: plus)
let resultminus = performOperation(1, 2, op: minus)
```

Often this would be preferred as it doesn't need methods to be added to a class, pretty much like anonymous functions in other languages.

---

More on this and how it is used in the swift standard library: https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend book "IOS 9 Programming Fundamentals with Swift" by Matt Neuburg, especially subchapter "Functions".

You should not only find the answer for your question:

```
func imageOfSize(size:CGSize, _ whatToDraw:() -> ()) -> UIImage {
   ...
}
```

But also how to construct function that returns the function:

```
func makeRoundedRectangleMaker(sz:CGSize) -> () -> UIImage { 
   ...
}
```

As well as brief introduction to Curried Functions.